# AuthenticatesUsers file does not exist in Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\

Tags: php, laravel

I set up a basic login/register system in Larave, and it is working perfectly, but I can't find the "AuthenticatesUsers" file to edit or just look at. All auth controllers reference to this file, but it simply doesn't exist. Where might it be?

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;
```

[image]

Comment: I found this question on Triage and don't know PHP so I just wanted to ask is it normal that you/re targeting `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers` but on the image I only see `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User`?

Comment: That is exactly the problem, the "AuthenticatesUsers" doesn't exist, only the User.php

Answer (score 2):

This strange thing happened in Laravel 7. They took out part of the authorization in a separate package laravel/ui.

Just use `composer require laravel/ui`

Answer (score 1):

For Laravel 7 the *AuthenticatesUsers* trait is located in;

```
vendor/laravel/ui/auth-backend/AuthenticatesUsers.php
```